# Problems printing to a plotter

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, pdf, printing

I have an excel sheet that goes from A75 - E75. Every time I print to the plotter it comes out super small. I have tried everything from changing margin size, ratio, paper size, scaling. I have exported to a pdf then tried printing that, nothing works.

I thought that maybe the sheet is simply just too big to be able to fit on a single page, but from what I understand about plotters, and from what many people have told me, that is not true.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I have tried everything I can possibly think of and nothing seems to work.

Comment: If your print from pdf has the same issue then you've to change your plotter settings. Please share a bit more details about that.

Comment: So youre saying that I have to physically be there to mess with the plotter? (I am helping a guy from another division of our company thats why I ask)

Answer (score 0):

Is the PDF format of the Excel file displayed normally? To better analyze this issue, could you share some screenshots with us?

Please open the Excel file and press *Ctrl+P* to preview whether the printing result achieves the expected effect.
If so, are there any issues when printing other files through this plotter?
I suggest you check if some plotter settings affect the printing effect.

In addition, I do not recommend that you print A75-E75 size Excel spreadsheets on a single sheet of paper. You can go to *View>Page Break Preview* to check how many pages your table has, and you can [add pages by going to *Page Layout>Insert Page Break*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-move-or-delete-page-breaks-in-a-worksheet-ad3dc726-beec-4a4c-861f-ed640612bdc2).
[image]

Comment: Im sorry but I cant share it. This file is through my company. I know its limited info im sorry. As for the page breaks, I will try that, I asked my boss and a few other people that know plotters better than me, they claim that it does not matter how big the sheet is with a plotter. (because it keeps rolling out paper until its finished). But I cant think of anything else.

Comment: Recreate the problem with mock data and share that with us

Comment: Do other files have this problem?
If you are willing to try, please just copy contents of the worksheet to a new blank workbook to check.